# AD B2C Authenticated user

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, msal.js, azure-authentication, aad-b2c

I have a usecase to integrate “ADB2C” with a “Java application” for a user authentication, and we are using a Microsoft MSAL libraries in the integration .
And here is a scenario that I’m facing currently, once a user navigates to the java web application and hit “Login” button then user redirect to the B2C SignIn page and user is getting authenticated successfully and we are receiving an access token successfully.

But, after user loggedIn and try accessing an authenticated apps on the website, then it’s asking the user to login again which is unexpected.
Please suggest me on this scenario, whether the changes have to make in the code or B2C custom policy side to overcome this issue. I really appreciate your time in considering this.

Comment: Have you set up Single Sign on? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on This should fix your problem Best,
James

Comment: Hi James. In B2C SignIn policy single Signon is enabled by default and it is authenticating a user if the session is still in active without prompting for relogin. But, in the front-end java application if this user hits any authenticated apps, then it is taking the user to login page again which is unexpected for already loggedIn user. If this is something we can fix from the java web-app, please share us some working scenarios. I really appreciate you time in considering this. Thank you!